Invalid characters in VARCHAR2 column - Oracle
I want to find out what characters are not supported in my VARCHAR2 column in Oracle. When I filter a VARCHAR2 field using asciistr(column) <> column (query provided below), I see that some characters are being replaced with '\00BF' code. I want to find out what are these characters so that I can add a condition to exclude them when collecting the data itself.
Query:
select name, asciistr(name) as encoded_name from table 
where asciistr(name) <> name

Output:



name
encoded_name




as¿d
as\00BFd


b¿ef
b\00BFef



I want to identify the characters that are being replaced with ¿ character in a VARCHAR2 column.

maybe you only have the wrong encoding did you try utf8mb4 or similar

I don't think I have the access to change the encoding of the table. This is an effort to identify and prevent the entry of such data in the future rather than fixing the current data. So, I want to identify the invalid characters when they are being submitted.

try the DUMP function: select DUMP(name) from ... then use the ASCII code with the CHR function to manipulate your data, or take action at the source as you say.

i am pretty sure, that your developer has the wrong encoding and sends utf8 or utf16 to the server column, which doesn't support the characters. Basically you can't "recover" any wrong charactersyoun need to  check which encoding you have in your column and see if the developer supports it

Are you sure these characters are not supported by the VARCHAR2 column? Nowadays Oracle runs on AL32UTF8 and all characters are supported. Most likely your client application uses the wrong character set and these characters are just not displayed. Or the character set was wrong when data was inserted. In this case you cannot identify them afterwards.

@WernfriedDomscheit Is it not possible to identify the characters after they are loaded on the database? The character set that is being used in 'WE8ISO8859P1'. In that case, I want to find out which characters are out of this character set. By any chance, do you know how I can identify such characters?

It's not possible. Unsupported characters are replaced by "¿", you cannot find out the original character anymore.

To identify the Unicode character ¿ or '\00bf', use condition like:
select name, 
    asciistr(name) as encoded_name 
from table 
where REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, unistr('\00bf'), 1) is not null;

To identify all names contains any Unicode character, query is:
select name, 
    asciistr(name) as encoded_name 
from table
where REGEXP_SUBSTR(asciistr(name), '\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}') is not null

To replace Unicode characters use query:
select name, asciistr(name),
   replace(name, unistr('\00bf')) as replace_single_unicode,
   REGEXP_REPLACE(asciistr(name), '\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}', '') as replace_all_unicode
from t0;


-- happy Coding

I don't want to replace the \00BF characters. I want to identify what are the characters that are being replaced with \00BF when the data is loaded onto Oracle DB.
